# permission problem when mirror a bucket, I'm trying to migrate a bucket of one minio server to another

Tags: minio

I'm trying to migrate a bucket of one minio server to another using mc client, the command that I'm using is mc mirror (mc mirror --remove --overwrite --preserve minioproducao/compartilhado minioteste/compartilhado) the command works fine, but I was cheeking some
permissions between both server inside the bucket and I realized that the permission are different, for example:
I've connected inside of the the both kubernetes container and run the ls -l inside the bucket directory
on the origin it was showed like this: **drwxr-xr-x arquivo.JPG**  #*ps: it's ins't a file its a directory[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXfdP.png) and inside of it there's two file like this: part.1 xl.meta*
on the destine it was showed like this: **-rw-r--r-- arquivo.JPG**  #*ps: it's was copied as as file not a directory like it's on the origin minio server bucket*
I'm wondering if there is a way to do a exactly copy of what's on my origin minio server, to another?
Thank you in advance!
Here's a picture that will help illustrate What I'm saying:
[image: Comparing permission between origin minio server and destiny minio server]

Comment: To solve the problem listed bellow, I have to change manualy the bucket permission, using the web interface.